# SharePoint 2010: In external application need to get all sites with write permission for logged in user. [C++]

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0, fast-for-sharepoint

In my external application I need to find all sites with write permission for logged in user. I am using Web Services. Is there any web service available for this task? Or can I send a Query and get the desired results?
I had thought of using the spsearch.asmx but I don't know how to proceed.

Earlier I was using the Web.asmx [getWebCollection] to get all the sites and then was using UserGroup.asmx [GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser] to get the permissions for each site for the logged in user, but this is a tedious method and takes a very long time.

I was hoping if we could use the spsearch.asmx to speed up the solution.

Comment: spsearch.asmx is used to invoke the search query engine to get search results, not for security related tasks like this.